# URLFOR with custombutton

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, custom-button

I want to create a custom button on parent record to add records in child object. I created the custom button with url for new child record on parent object but the parent name does not auto populate in the new child record edit mode and I have to enter it manually and then save the record. Is their a way to get this working.

Here is my code,

```
!URLFOR($Action.Rep_Expense__c.New,null,["00No0000000lFwWEAU"=Contact.Id],true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at a quick action vs using a custom button url hack since they do not work in Lightning experience and are not supported by salesforce and therefor could break without notice but if you want to continue with the URL hack then you need to change your paramaters to set both the id and the name and also include CF before the field ID for custom fields: `{!URLFOR($Action.Rep_Expense__c.New,null,[CF00No0000000lFwWEAU=Contact.Id, CF00No0000000lFwWEAU_lkid=Contact.Name],true)}`

Comment: I used the code and got the below error.  SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.Name

Comment: @Dinesh is this button be placed on a visualforce page and if yes does that visualforce page have access to the contact name?

Comment: Yes Jenny, the button is on visualforce page and it do have access to contact name field.  <apex:page standardController="Contact">

Comment: @Dinesh but do you specifically have the Name field rendered on the page?

Comment: Yes, I have rendered Name field in page. I created custom button with this code "/a08/e?CF00No0000000lFwW={!Contact.Name}&CF00No0000000lFwW_lkid={!Contact.Id}" and now its working fine. Thanks Jenny for helping me to fix the issue.

Comment: The above code is working fine from related list but not from visualforce page. could you help me with this one.

Comment: @Dinesh are you getting the soql error from the vf page or what's not working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31154/discussion-between-jenny-b-and-dinesh).

Comment: I created a custom button with above code and refered it in a VF page. The URL didn't populate with values.   action="{!URLFOR($Action.Rep_Expense__c.New_Rep_Expense)}"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [URL Hacking](http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/).

> As a quick recap – URL hacking is the process of pre-populating data
>   in a new record with data from a record you are currently working off
>   using a custom button to launch this new record.